# Could not find the correct Provider<customer_paymentCRUD> above this Customer_payment_page> Widget - flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-moor

> > This mistake happens
> >     I work on this project and I have this error, try to solve it in many ways 
> >     But is not work manually

I have to call Model in this class and I want to put the value from another screen 
can anyone help me

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:login_example/CustomerCore/viewmodels/CRUDModel.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'CustomerCore/models/cstomer_payment_detailsModel.dart';
import 'CustomerCore/models/productModel.dart';
import 'CustomerCore/viewmodels/customer_paymentCRUD.dart';

class customer_payment_page extends StatefulWidget {
final Customers_Information customer_info;

customer_payment_page({@required this.customer_info});
@override
custmomer_payment createState() =>
  custmomer_payment(customer_info: customer_info);
}

class custmomer_payment extends State<customer_payment_page> {
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

final Customers_Information customer_info;

custmomer_payment({@required this.customer_info});

final FocusNode _firstInputFocusNode = new FocusNode();
final FocusNode _secondInputFocusNode = new FocusNode();

showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
// set up the button
Widget okButton = FlatButton(
  child: Text("OK"),
  onPressed: () {
    // Navigator.pop(context);
  },
);

// set up the AlertDialog
AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
  ),
  title: Text("عملية اضافة",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl),
  content: Text("تمت اضافة الزبون بنجاح",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl),
  backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
  actions: [
    //   okButton,
  ],
);

// show the dialog
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return alert;
  },
);
 }
customer_fountshowAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
  // set up the button
  Widget okButton = FlatButton(
  child: Text("OK"),
  onPressed: () {
    // Navigator.pop(context);
  },
  );

  // set up the AlertDialog
  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
    ),
  title: Text("عملية اضافة",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl),
  content: Text("هذا الاسم متواجد ",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl),
  backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
  actions: [
    //   okButton,
  ],
  );

  // show the dialog
  showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return alert;
  },
  );
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final customer_paymentProvider = Provider.of<customer_paymentCRUD>(context);

Future<bool> _goToLogin(BuildContext context) {
  return Navigator.of(context)
      .pushReplacementNamed('/')
      // we dont want to pop the screen, just replace it completely
      .then((_) => false);
}

return MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
```

> this error when I run the project and open this screen

[image]

Comment: which provider version are you using?

Comment: @Abbas  I using this (  provider: ^3.0.1)

Comment: you should include the full code including ChangeNotifierProvider and the model itself

Comment: you can check where is your provider located in your widget tree, it should be located as a parent widget above your widget.